# Insert data in two tables using one query

Tags: database, sql-insert

In php mysql, how can i enter data in two tables simultaneously with both tables having a primary key - foreign key relationship. say for example.

Table 1

```
id(P.K) | username | password
```

Table 2

```
id(F.K) | fname | lname | email
```

i have researched, and i don't wanna use last_insert_id() or mysql_insert_id(). Are there any other methods?

Comment: Why don't you want to use last_insert_id or similar? Aside from not using an identity column, the answer is no. Not using an identity would be hard to recommend and you'd still want to insert to both in the same transaction anyway...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one of then (and the best IMHO) is creating an trigger on your primary table that will update your second table. Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <trigger name> AFTER INSERT ON <your_primary_table>
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @id = NEW.id;
    INSERT INTO <your_second_table>(id) VALUES (@id);
END;
```